# Why is the Camera Position Zoom different from tiles' Zoom level in Mapbox GL Android?

Tags: android, zooming, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I am showing the CameraPosition Zoom in a label on Mapview, and using a custom raster tiles' source and have noticed that the zoom level of tiles being shown on mapview and the zoom level of camera are actually different (For example, at Camera Zoom 14.something i was getting tiles for zoom level 16).

Does somebody know why could that have happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to maximize imagery sharpness throughout the fractional zoom range, raster tiles transition at half-zoom levels in Mapbox SDKs. So for instance, a z14 raster tile is used for the range [z13.5, z14.5).

(If you are using 256 pixel raster tiles, you may also observe a difference of +/- 1 zoom level between the zoom level reported by the map, and the zoom level in tile URLs. This is because Mapbox GL zoom levels are calibrated against 512 pixel tiles. 256 pixel tiles are therefore loaded at +1 z relative to the map zoom.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, in our app the user has to download tiles and we need the current zoom level of the tiles that are being shown on the mapview to show the user so that he/she has a better idea about the detail of the tiles he/she is downloading, is there an api or some way of finding out the current zoom level of the tilesource?